# mysqld_safe not starting after install MySQL 5.7.13 port in FreeBSD/amd64 10.3 using pkg

Tags: freebsd, mysql

I have a problem with running mysql server. I've just installed FreeBSD 10.3 and I want to run here MySQL server, but process doesn't starts.

Here are all commands i gave after install FreeBSD, step-by-step:

```
portsnap fetch extract
pkg update
pkg install mysql57-server
```

/* Here mysql says about .mysql_secret file with password to root, but it's not generating at all. I can use but there is no result... */

```
find / -iname .mysql_secret
```

When I try to first run MySQL using this command:

```
mysqld_safe --initialize --user=mysql
```

I get this one:

```
mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/db/mysql/host.err'
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld deamon with databases from /var/db/mysql
mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/host.pid ended
```

Here you are /var/db/mysql/host.err

```
2016-08-22T11:56:27.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
2016-08-22T11:56:27.533572Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2016-08-22T11:56:27.533635Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-08-22T11:56:27.6NZ mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/host.pid ended
```

I found something simmilar:

https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/56275/

https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209512

There is still no solution. Any ideas? I really need MySQL. I have tried with MySQL 5.6 too. Same problem...

At the end /usr/local/etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
# $FreeBSD: branches/2016Q3/databases/mysql57-server/files/my.cnf.sample.in 414707 2016-05-06 14:39:59Z riggs $

[client]
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock

[mysql]
prompt                          = \u@\h [\d]>\_
no_auto_rehash

[mysqld]
user                            = mysql
port                            = 3306
socket                          = /tmp/mysql.sock
bind-address                    = 127.0.0.1
basedir                         = /usr/local
datadir                         = /var/db/mysql
tmpdir                          = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
slave-load-tmpdir               = /var/db/mysql_tmpdir
secure-file-priv                = /var/db/mysql_secure
log-bin                         = mysql-bin
log-output                      = TABLE
master-info-repository          = TABLE
relay-log-info-repository       = TABLE
relay-log-recovery              = 1
slow-query-log                  = 1
server-id                       = 1
sync_binlog                     = 1
sync_relay_log                  = 1
binlog_cache_size               = 16M
expire_logs_days                = 30
default_password_lifetime       = 0
enforce-gtid-consistency        = 1
gtid-mode                       = ON
safe-user-create                = 1
lower_case_table_names          = 1
explicit-defaults-for-timestamp = 1
myisam-recover-options          = BACKUP,FORCE
open_files_limit                = 32768
table_open_cache                = 16384
table_definition_cache          = 8192
net_retry_count                 = 16384
key_buffer_size                 = 256M
max_allowed_packet              = 64M
query_cache_type                = 0
query_cache_size                = 0
long_query_time                 = 0.5
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 1G
innodb_data_home_dir            = /var/db/mysql
innodb_log_group_home_dir       = /var/db/mysql
innodb_data_file_path           = ibdata1:128M:autoextend
innodb_temp_data_file_path      = ibtmp1:128M:autoextend
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size            = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 16M
innodb_write_io_threads         = 8
innodb_read_io_threads          = 8
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode        = 2
skip-symbolic-links

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet              = 256M
quote_names
quick
```

Comment: Just as an aside, you do not need to do `portsnap fetch extract` if you are using `pkg` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found solution myself:

```
cd /var/db/mysql #IMPORTANT STEP
/usr/local/libexec/mysqld --initialize --user=mysql #SECOND IMPORTANT STEP
echo mysql_enable="YES" >> /etc/rc.conf
service mysql-server start
mysql -u root -p (here password randomly generated from the terminal)
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the database. This is already handled in the FreeBSD startup script, but it's probably not too difficult to do it the hard way. Look at the `mysql_install_db` utility.

However, if you add the following to your `/etc/rc.conf` file:

```
mysql_enable="YES"
```

Then the `mysql_install_db` utility will be run automatically first time through.

The service is started automatically at boot time, or manually using the [`service` command](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=service):

```
service mysql start
```

Comment: mysql_install_db is deprecated so I used
    mysqld_safe --initialize --user=mysql

Answer (score 1):

Before being able to run your mysql command you will need to start the mysql service by doing the following as root:

```
echo mysql_enable="YES" >> /etc/rc.conf
service mysql start
```

This will then generate the file `/root/.mysql_secret` which contains the initial password for 'root'@'localhost'.  You will then be able to run your mysql command.